# Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2012 Export to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

On my Dev PC I am using Crystal Reports for VS2012. I have Adobe Reader 11 installed on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

On my production server, I have the 64-bit Crystal runtime installed alongside Adobe Reader 11. The servers runs Windows Server 2008 (obviously 64-bit)

Reports export to PDF perfectly on the dev box, but on the server they are coming out with the fonts all over the place - not just some shrinking, but others becoming massive too.

I have tried the fix in the registry, putting "ForceLargerFonts" etc, but that was aimed at fixing a CR2008 issue - and my fonts aren't going small, they are going random sizes!

Has anyone else had this issue and found a solution?

Comment: Two things I would check: did you install the runtime on the production server as msi or exe? Do you have the same runtime versions (i.e. 13.x.x) on your machines?

Comment: 13.0.5 was on both dev and production, I just found 13.0.7 so I updated to that but it made no difference.

Comment: Did you make sure to use the exe installer, not the msi?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://scn.sap.com/thread/3283902

Comment: What is your code for exporting to a PDF?

Comment: ValuationReport.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, FileName);